# ErrorException Undefined variable on Blade View when trying to View Different Contents in Laravel 7

Tags: sql, laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

I am trying to do a foreach loop on the header of my dashboard.blade.php inside layouts folder with

```
@foreach ($moneytrades as $mt)
 <div class="col mr-2">
      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Deposited</div>            
      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Php {{ $mt->mt_deposit}}</div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

my web.php route is

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

On my HomeController I have

```
public function index()
{
    $moneytrades = MoneyTrade::all();

    return view('layouts.dashboard', compact('moneytrades'));
}
```

And this works totally fine. However, I have a `@yield('content')` just below the loop and whenever I click on a button to route to a new page I'm getting this error message

`ErrorException Undefined variable: moneytrades (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\fss\resources\views\layouts\dashboard.blade.php)`

What can I do to fix this so that all the contents extended by `layouts.dashboard` would work with these foreach loop? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a partial(for which you are doing `@yield('content')` ), you can use view components.

```
<div class="container">
        @component('content', ['moneytrades' => $moneytrades])
        @endcomponent
</div>
```

Then access in your component content,

```
   <div class="col-md-8">
         @foreach ($moneytrades as $mt)
            {{-- do whatever you want  --}}
         @endforeach
   </div>
```

Edit : View Components in blade components is available for Laravel >= 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

you can use view composers to share date across multiple views.
for example in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider you can add:

```
View::composer(
    ['dashboard', 'other-view'],
    'App\Http\View\Composers\DashboardComposer'
);
```

and create a composer: "App\Http\View\Composers\DashboardComposer" for example

```
class DashboardComposer
{    
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('moneytrades', MoneyTrade::all());
    }
}
```

now all views registered with the composer will have access to $moneytrades.
and from the action only return the view:

```
return view('layouts.dashboard'); // or any other registered view
```

checkout the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Comment: That's a very helpful information. Thank you so much! :)